# DiscordAPIError: Missing Access Discord V13 slash commands

Tags: discord, discord.js

I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Users\faray\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\ShinsuBotHost\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\faray\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\ShinsuBotHost\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\faray\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\ShinsuBotHost\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (C:\Users\faray\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\ShinsuBotHost\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:146:18)
    at async C:\Users\faray\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\ShinsuBotHost\handlers\slash_handler.js:30:21 {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/939213917958324234/guilds/932047617809068083/commands',
  code: 50001,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: [
      {
        name: 'hey',
        description: undefined,
        type: 3,
        options: undefined,
        default_permission: undefined
      },
      {
        name: 'ping',
        description: 'show ping',
        type: undefined,
        options: undefined,
        default_permission: undefined
      }
    ],
    files: []
  }
}
```

I've tried all the solutions proposed on the internet but none of them work. I've added all the permissions possible and the `bot` and `applications.commands` scopes to the bot. I am hosting my bot with Heroku.

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833215/discord-js-discordapierror-missing-access

Comment: ive already visited that question before and i've followed the steps proposed. however, it doesn't solve my problem. I get the same error

Comment: Could you share your bot link used to invite your bot (make sure to remove any keys/tokens)?

Comment: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&scope=bot%20applications.commands&permissions=1099511627775

Comment: Does your bot use slash commands? If they do, you will need to select `applications.commands` in the scopes of the bot

Comment: @NobleKnightMail you will need to be sure to invite it again if you invited it without the scope before

Comment: I've invited it with the scopes before. I've tried it multiple times.